# Swift: Assuming static for 'let' fields with iniital value

Tags: swift, static

Please correct me if I am wrong, but it looks like a constant (`let`) field with initial value specified in declaration (rather than obtained in a constructor) can be assumed `static` as this value will be same for all instances of the class. I wonder if Swift compiler caters for that.

The need to explicitly specify class name for all static fields (`MyClass.myStaticField` instead of just `staticField`) really annoys me, but if the constants are implicitly static, dropping `static` keyword would allow referring them by just variable name, which makes the code concise and better readable.

Comment: `static` denotes that their is no need for an instance of the `struct`/`class`, where as plain `let` requires an instance of it's containing container and can applied to functions as well (`static` that is)

Comment: MadProgrammer  We are not discussing the meaning of 'let' and 'static' keywords. The question was quite specific.

Comment: Really, because I have no idea what you're asking

Comment: Can you edit your post to ask a specific question? I too thought you were confused about the difference `let` and `static`.

Comment: @cyanide I understand what you are asking. But I think it would help to show a clear and simple example in your question to make it clearer to others.

Comment: @maddy. Having same filed in all instances of a class would be a waste of space. That's why all constants are normally declared as static. Actually I declare a filed as static even in a sigleton,  provided it is conceptually instant-independent, Unfortunately Swift (as I explained above) makes using static fields rather inconvenient.  It will be great if Swift autmatically makes all 'let' constants with initial value static, which makes sense to me. Should I add something to that? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functionally it would be similar to a static property, but if you make a constant that is assigned a value as an instance variable (e.g. you don't specify it is static) then it will still be a constant on an instance, granted they're identical across instances. Might as well just make it static and have it belong to the class at that point. So to answer your question, no, it is not assumed to be static, it must still be marked static if it is static.

Comment: Again this is not about the meaning of static keyword. The question is: are 'let' fields with initial value are assumed to be static even if static keyword is not coded?  I also explained why I am asking this question. I believe the question is clear and straightforward.

Comment: Oh, I see. Sorry, the question wasn't clear to me. Well, functionally it would be similar to a static property, but if you make a constant that is assigned a value as an instance variable (e.g. you don't specify it is static) then it will still be a constant on an instance, granted they're identical across instances. Might as well just make it static and have it belong to the class at that point. So to answer your question, no, it is not assumed to be static, it must still be marked static if it is static. Editing my answer to reflect.